# Why Browser can issue XHR POST request while JMeter and Curl cant

Tags: spring, post, jmeter, xmlhttprequest

Investigating a web resource's behavior I found out that there is a **POST** request (as it is stated in Web Inspector) made as XHR (AJAX) with some parameters and request headers. Among others there is a **X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest** meaning that the request is AJAX.

When I try to make the same request with JMeter or Curl I get an error telling the following (providing all necessary headers) :

> Request method 'POST' not supported

I have source of the app and service of my interest has the following definition:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/myrestservice")
public class MyRestServiceController {
// some code goes here

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, DataDTO> getRestServiceResponse(@RequestParam("list") final List<String> itemsList, final Model model)
```

So it has to accept POST requests. And it **does** when it comes in runtime, but it doesn't for me trying to make such a request **manually**.

Any ideas why this kind of discrepancy happens?[image: JMeter screenshot]
[image: web inspector header][image: web inspector request][image: web inspector response]

This is the **Request** snipped from **View Results Tree**:
POST https:${address-goes-here}/productstock/get/

> POST data:
>   CSRFToken=720fe025-d511-4a5e-ab17-d1ea8e0b0aa3&productList=productList%3D000000000010000545%2C000000000010000553%2C000000000010012169
>
> Cookie Data:
>   JSESSIONID=60409DB1AFD720283100BCA212CD42DE.app11; megapolisstorefrontRememberMe=cGV0cjE0NzhAbWFpbC5ydToxNTIwMjQzMjExMzc5Ojk2Z> TkzN2FlNzY5MDk5NmY4ZDk5N2JhMTQ5MmEzYmI5; > acceleratorSecureGUID=ca22a2f520a00f5cc3efa3acb6599a5f0e081c85
>
> Request Headers: Connection: keep-alive Accept: application/json,
>   text/javascript
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 Origin:
>   ${address-goes-here}
>   Referer:
>   ${address-goes-here}/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/c/2006
>   Content-Length: 147
>   Host: ${address-goes-here}
>   User-Agent:
>   Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_112)

Comment: I guess you must put the right content-type header `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: can you show your working (in web inspector) and not working in JMeter request?

Comment: Well, as I wrote - all necessary headers are there, including "Accept: application/json" and "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of JMeter (Ctrl+G). It could be a typo or a misunderstanding in header variables

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Make sure to perform correlation of the `CSRFToken` dynamic parameter. Check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more details.

My expectation is that you try to perform a request directly, however you need to be logged in (have valid cookie and CSRF token). If you have login sequence in place examine response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener - most probably your test hits login page only and it doesn't support POST request types.

Comment: Well, I do have HTTP Cookie Manager in my test plan, in the very root of it, so any other HTTP Samples "knows" about it.  CSRFToken is carefully extracted also.  And, for pages - test certainly meets dedicated page, not login by mistake.  Test plan in quite complex in its structure and the only thing that doesn't work there - is this very request, which is done perfectly by the app (I can see it in web inspector), but cant be done by me (JMeter)...  Anyway, thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

So, the whole point was in wrong csrftoken sent to the service.

As long as I provided the correct one, request succeeded.